# Dial a number when entering a location - iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, location

I have a small question. Is it possible to create a small program that call a given number, when you get home (based on GPS). The garage door opens / closes by calling a number.

Comment: The user will still have to confirm the phone call, but yes, that should be generally possible to do so.

Comment: How does the garage door respond to a phone number?  That would entail a custom phone system in the house.  You may be better off having the App connect to a local WiFi connection when at the GPS co-ords and then fire off a message to a WiFi/Ethernet based hardware switch that will control the door.

Comment: If your question is answered, please don't forget to select an answer!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it is possible.

You can use:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel:XXXXXX"]];
```

(taken from: [Call to a phone number through iPhone App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2818968/call-to-a-phone-number-through-iphone-app))

You should be able to set it up to perform this function based on gps location.  Just get the coordinates you need and pass them to a method.  Test them to see if they fall within a certain range and if so, call the number.

Answer (score 1):

just compare two location (home and current position) and call the number which will open gate. Simple way to do this is

```
CLLocation *loc1 = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:lat1 longitude:lon1];
double distance = [loc1 getDistanceFrom:position2];

if(distance <= 5 (any value you want)) {
   [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel:XXXXXX"]]; 
}
```